# Ruby On Rails ActiveRecord SQL view into schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-view

I created a view and was able to successfully access it through rails by creating the view through a migration with execute sql.

The problem with this is that the view is not entered into the schema.  So when I need to create my test database to run my tests against the view is not created.  I then need to create it by running the sql statement. Is there a way to implement SQL views elegantly in ruby on rails?

My environment:
Ruby on Rails 3.0.3
PostgreSQL 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rails_sql_views gem](http://activewarehouse.rubyforge.org/rails_sql_views/) is intended to solve this problem. It adds support to the schema dumper to include views, which means you can use them in your test database. I'm not sure how well it works in Rails 3, but the github issues list has a pull request that appears to add Rails 3 support.

Comment: This did solve my problem although there were a few pauses for concern.  I had to edit the code for it to work with Postgres.

Comment: Nicolo77>  Could you share what code change you made to make the gem work with postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. using `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` may help.